# Autoproxy alternative to Google Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, autoproxy

Proxy Switch does not work on my computer, is there any other alternative to AutoProxy in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2011/06/how-to-configure-auto-proxying-in.html